# Untouching methods doesn't work in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I've write a directive for textarea Html tag to submit a description to an API. I need to set this tag untouched after I submit the data. I use  `$scope.$setPristine()` and then `$scope.apply()` but this doesn't work!I also tried `ngModelCtrl.$setUntouched()` and I got same result.

The Directive tag is as below:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
     <dp-text-area 
         dp-tabindex="11"
         label="Description"
         placeholder="Description"
         ng-model="vm.cityModel.description">
     </dp-text-area>
</div>
```

Here is the directive JavaScript code:

```
 function dpTextArea($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            placeholder: '@',
            externalNgModel: '=ngModel',
            editDisabled: '@',
            ngRequired: '=',
            dpTabindex: '='
        },
        link(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
                var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
                if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                    if (fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
                        fn();
                    }
                } else {
                    this.$apply(fn);
                }};
            scope.$watch(() => {
                return scope.editDisabled;
            }, (n, o) => {
                // if (n == o)return;
                if (scope.editDisabled === 'false') {
                    scope.editDisabled = false;
                }
            });
            scope.isTextareaTouched = false;
            scope.isTextareaInvalid = false;
            if (scope.ngRequired)
                scope.isTextareaInvalid = true;
            scope.blurFunc = () => {
                scope.isTextareaTouched = true;
            };
            //#region watch $error
            scope.$watch(
                function () {
                    let rtn = JSON.stringify(ngModelCtrl.$error);
                    return rtn;
                },
                function (n, o) {
                    if (n == o) return;
                    if (Object.keys(ngModelCtrl.$error).length == 0) {
                        scope.isTextareaInvalid = false;
                    } else {
                        scope.isTextareaInvalid = true;
                    }
                });
            //#endregion
            },
        template: require('./dpTextArea.directive.html')
        }}
    export default angular.module('directives.dpTextArea', [])
    .directive('dpTextArea', dpTextArea)
    .name;
```

And here is the template of the directive:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':isTextareaInvalid && isTextareaTouched}">
<label class="control-label">
    {{label || 'description'}}
    <sup class="text-danger" ng-show="ngRequired">*</sup>
</label>
<textarea rows="3" type="text"
          tabindex="{{dpTabindex}}"
          class="form-control"
          ng-class="{'edit-disabled':editDisabled}"
          ng-disabled="editDisabled"
          placeholder="{{placeholder || 'description'}}"
          ng-model="externalNgModel"
          ng-required="ngRequired"
          ng-blur="blurFunc()"
></textarea>

<small class="help-block" ng-show="isTextareaInvalid && isTextareaTouched">this field is requred.</small>
```

I appreciate any help.